# How to read request body from HttpAsyncRequestProducer?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, request, apache-httpasyncclient

I am unable to get request body from this `HttpAsyncRequestProducer` of `org.apache.http.nio.protocol`.

I also want to read the request body multiple times.

**My Usecase:**

I am intercepting **execute** method of `InternalHttpAsyncClient` of `org.apache.http.impl.nio.client` (which has an argument called `HttpAsyncRequestProducer`) using Bytebuddy and trying to capture request and response and save it.

Since ElasticSearch using High level rest-client is ultimately using this client's method only.
So, for this purpose I want to read the request body multiple times.

```java
public <T> Future<T> execute(HttpAsyncRequestProducer requestProducer, HttpAsyncResponseConsumer<T> responseConsumer, HttpContext context, FutureCallback<T> callback) {
        this.ensureRunning();
        BasicFuture<T> future = new BasicFuture(callback);
        HttpClientContext localcontext = HttpClientContext.adapt((HttpContext)(context != null ? context : new BasicHttpContext()));
        this.setupContext(localcontext);
        DefaultClientExchangeHandlerImpl<T> handler = new DefaultClientExchangeHandlerImpl(this.log, requestProducer, responseConsumer, localcontext, future, this.connmgr, this.connReuseStrategy, this.keepaliveStrategy, this.exec);

        try {
            handler.start();
        } catch (Exception var9) {
            handler.failed(var9);
        }

        return new FutureWrapper(future, handler);
    }
```

Above is the actual method i am intercepting with the below interceptor.

```
 @RuntimeType
    public static Future<Object> doProceed(@Origin Method method, @SuperCall Callable<Future<Object>> callable, @AllArguments Object[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Inside ElasticSearchInterceptor");

        System.out.println("ElasticSearchInterceptor: Method-> " + method);

        int i = 0;
        for (Object obj : args) {
            System.out.println("Argument[" + i + "]: " + obj);
            i++;
        }

        HttpAsyncRequestProducer requestProducer = (HttpAsyncRequestProducer) args[0];

   // how to read the request body?????


        HttpRequest httpRequest = requestProducer.generateRequest();

        System.out.println("ElasticSearchInterceptor: Request Headers-> " + Arrays.toString(httpRequest.getAllHeaders()));



        System.out.println("ElasticSearchInterceptor: Before call");
        Future<Object> call = callable.call();
        HttpResponse res = (HttpResponse) call.get();
        System.out.println("Response in elastic search " + res);

        System.out.println("ElasticSearchInterceptor: After call");

        return call;
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide a piece of code so that others can better understand your problem.

Comment: Is this better potrayed now?